# Select2 - Close dropdown when clicking outside of the dropdown or pressing "done" on iOS keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-select2

I have a Select2 dropdown on my website and I would like for the dropdown to close if the user clicks outside of the dropdown and also if they hit "done" on the keyboard in iOS. Here's my attempt(neither goal has been achieved):

```js
$(function() {
  $('select').select2({
    dropdownAutoWidth : true
  });
  
  // My attempt at closing the dropdown on press of "done"
  $('select').bind("keypress", function(e){
     if(e.which === 13){
       $('select').select2('close');
      } 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<select>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
  <option>Option 4</option>
  <option>Option 5</option>
  <option>Option 6</option>
  <option>Option 7</option>
  <option>Option 8</option>
  <option>Option 9</option>
  <option>Option 10</option>
</select>
```